# User defined type not defined on Snapshot and Database

Tags: vb6

I am using vb6 but following did not work at all:

```
Dim Sn as Snapshot
Dim db as Database
```

Each statement generates an error.

```
USER DEFINED TYPE NOT DEFINED
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: @SteveChambers The compiler error indicates that VB6 does not know, and the OP doesn't know either (otherwise they probably wouldn't ask). In fact Snapshot was an old object for accessing databases in VB3 (yes VB3), roughly equivalent to Recordset in DAO/ADO. See my answer for more.

Comment: To everyone that down-voted the question, please provide reasons.  The OP provided the code that failed and the error message.  Just because a question is *easy* for a subject-matter expert doesn't mean it's a bad question.  Come on folks, recognize that we all were first-time posters at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable types `Snapshot` and `Database` are not defined. That means that Visual Basic does not know the definition of those words. They are either undefined, or a reference is missing from your project.

Answer (score 0):

@denis You are using the object/DataType which are not predefined,

So you have to define that first as per your requirements..

for example

```
Private Type Snapshot
    snapID as String
    snapName as String
    snapTime as Date
End Type
```

here, I have defined the object snapshot with 3 values within.

For more details please go to this [Reference](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/user-defined-types-udt-vb), here you will find more explanation and detail.

Next time when you raise question on stack OverFlow please do some home work on your own, as this is site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

I hope this will do..

Comment: @down-marker please provide some input, so that I can improve my answer, thank you..

Comment: It wasn't me that down-voted, but I'd disagree that "this is experts forum".  If we are all experts, then why have a forum at all...we must know everything.  Beginners / newbies are welcome too.

Comment: I am partially agree with your thoughts so but this things are quite basic that are served on web that is easily available.. please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/about >> in don'ts this says 1) Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!). I am willing to answer but at the same point we have to see in 10th standard we should not teach ABCD(Primary). please don't take anything personally, its rule by the site.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at some code that was originally written for a very old version of VB - VB3? `Snapshot` is an [old object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109218) for accessing databases, roughly equivalent to Recordset in DAO/ADO.

Are you trying to upgrade an old project to VB6!? You could add a reference to the `Microsoft DAO 2.5/3.51 Compatibility Library`. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129883) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240377)

Or you could rewrite your code to use VB6/ADO. Or if you're going to rewrite, why not VB.Net / ADO.Net.